# Rails: add typeahead to a form for a simple static JSON file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, typeahead, typeahead.js

Im trying to add a simple twitter typeahead.js to a rails form like this one.

```
<label for="inputStreet" class="control-label">Street Name</label>               
<%= f.text_field :street_name,  data: {autocomplete_source: '/suggestions.json'}, class: 'form-control', autofocus: true %>
```

I've also just tried using static typeahead like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.typeahead').typeahead( {name: 'planets', local: [ "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune" ] });
});
```

with HTML like this

```
<input id="typeahead" class="form-control">
```

But nothings happening. I've followed every instructions there is. JS console show's no error.
Im using Rails4 with the gem [twitter-typeahead-rails](https://github.com/yourabi/twitter-typeahead-rails)

Am I doing something wrong or? Can anybody show me how they would do this in rails?

Answer (score 0):

There is your problem clearly, you `input` has `id="typeahead"`, and you are initializing typeahead with class `.typeahead`. What you should do is change it to use id selector `#typeahead`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'planets', 
        local: ["Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"] 
    });
});
```